# PHP7.0-FPM with Docker : Unable to load dynamic library OCI8

Tags: php, oracle, docker, oracle-call-interface, fpm

I have created a Docker Image with PHP7.0-FPM and Apache 2.4. I have installed InstantClient 12.2 (basic + sdk) and I have installed oci8 like this :

`RUN echo "instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient"| pecl install oci8 && \
    echo "extension=oci8.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/oci8.ini && \
    ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/oci8.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-oci8.ini`

I don't know why, but I am getting this warning when I (re)start php7.0-fpm :

`# service php7.0-fpm restart
 * Restarting PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager php-fpm7.0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Locations of oci8.so and libmql1.so seems to be ok :

```
# ll /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient/
total 216700
drwxrwxrwx 3 root www-data      4096 Dec 11 15:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root www-data      4096 Dec 12 08:24 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data       363 Jan 26  2017 BASIC_README*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data     44220 Jan 26  2017 adrci*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data     57272 Jan 26  2017 genezi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data        52 Dec 11 15:02 libclntsh.so -> /usr/lib/oracl
e/12.2/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data  71638263 Jan 26  2017 libclntsh.so.12.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data   8033199 Jan 26  2017 libclntshcore.so.12.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data   2981501 Jan 26  2017 libipc1.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data    539065 Jan 26  2017 libmql1.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data   6568149 Jan 26  2017 libnnz12.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            50 Dec 11 15:12 libocci.so -> /usr/lib/oracle/
12.2/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data   2218687 Jan 26  2017 libocci.so.12.1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data 124771800 Jan 26  2017 libociei.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data    158543 Jan 26  2017 libocijdbc12.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data    380996 Jan 26  2017 libons.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data    116563 Jan 26  2017 liboramysql12.so*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data   4036257 Jan 26  2017 ojdbc8.jar*
drwxrwxrwx 5 root www-data      4096 Jan 26  2017 sdk/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data    240476 Jan 26  2017 uidrvci*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data     74230 Jan 26  2017 xstreams.jar*
```

I have added to `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` these 4 lines :

`env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient
env[TNS_ADMIN] = /etc/oracle
env[ORACLE_BASE] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient
env[ORACLE_HOME] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient`

Would I've missed something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok !
I was missing a `.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf`

```
RUN echo "instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient"| pecl install oci8 && \
echo "extension=oci8.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/oci8.ini && \
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/oci8.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-oci8.ini && \
echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
ldconfig
```

Comment: That might also be the reason as echo will open file specified even its not exists with empty lines, have try with that with .conf

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those env variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
add at end of the file, like

- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient
- export TNS_ADMIN=/etc/oracle
- export ORACLE_BASE=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient
- export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/instantclient

So that apache user will use those variable at runtime.
And also check for user/group permission it has to be www-data:www-data

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already done but there is no changes.
Also, i think it's php-fpm and not apache, no?

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME or ORACLE_BASE for Instant Client.  They are used for full Oracle database and full Oracle client installs.