# php-oci8 - libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: php, php-7.2, rhel6

In RHEL 6 I have installed PHP 7.2 via remi repository:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php
```

Checked which modules are preinstalled with `php -m`. It is not listed. So I proceed to install it:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 php72-php-oci8

Installed:
  php72-php-oci8.x86_64 0:7.2.17-1.el6.remi

Complete!
```

Check modules again and oci8 not yet loaded. In order to test if it fails with all modules I tried with `mbstring` (not installed by default):

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-mbstring
Installed:
  php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.2.17-1.el6.remi

Complete!
```

If I do `php -m` mbstring successfully listed there. Am I missing something with `oci8`?  Thank you in advance.

#### Update

I have added the extension into php.ini file with `extension=oci8`. Then I did `php -m`:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Looks like php can not find `libclntsh.so.18.1` library from Oracle client. So I decided to check the oracle's home lib to take look:

```
# ls -l libclntsh*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle oinstall       61 Mar 26 16:20 libclntsh.so -> /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle oinstall       56 Mar 26 16:19 libclntsh.so.10.1 -> /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 47251283 Mar 26 16:20 libclntsh.so.11.1
```

What I am thinking is that the oci8 extension is trying to load this library for 18c oracle version while my current client is 11g. No idea on how to solve it.

Comment: There must be something in your PHP log showing a startup error?

Comment: @miken32, your light me in order to solve it. I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (PHP 7.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833041/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-so-php-7-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, it is necessary to download `Oracle Client 18.5.0 Base - Linux x86-64`  here:

> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Unzip sources as `oracle` user:

```
$ cd /u01/app/oracle/product/
$ mkdir 18.5.0
$ cd 18.5.0
$ wget -c https://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/185000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.5.0.0.0dbru.zip?AuthParam=1555443721_28dfadc632483f950d87ee5f54810e06 -O instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
$ unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

Doing `ls` you can confirm that the library is right there:

```
$ ls -l instantclient_18_5/
total 227712
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall     42360 Feb 26 20:04 adrci
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall      5780 Feb 26 20:04 BASIC_LICENSE
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall      1632 Feb 26 20:04 BASIC_README
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall     66672 Feb 26 20:04 genezi
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 oracle oinstall   8357160 Feb 26 20:04 libclntshcore.so.18.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle oinstall        17 Apr 16 20:42 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.18.1
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 oracle oinstall  78200832 Feb 26 20:04 libclntsh.so.18.1
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall   3551217 Feb 26 20:04 libipc1.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall    467932 Feb 26 20:04 libmql1.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall   6636088 Feb 26 20:04 libnnz18.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle oinstall        15 Apr 16 20:42 libocci.so -> libocci.so.18.1
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall   2282891 Feb 26 20:04 libocci.so.18.1
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 126959616 Feb 26 20:04 libociei.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall    160875 Feb 26 20:04 libocijdbc18.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall    394835 Feb 26 20:04 libons.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall    117635 Feb 26 20:04 liboramysql18.so
drwxr-xr-x. 3 oracle oinstall      4096 Feb 26 20:04 network
-r--r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   4161744 Feb 26 20:04 ojdbc8.jar
-r--r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   1398331 Feb 26 20:04 ucp.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall    242008 Feb 26 20:04 uidrvci
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall     74263 Feb 26 20:04 xstreams.jar
```

Finnaly, it is mandatory to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable in order to let PHP where to find the library:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/instantclient_18_5
```

Now, you can check that `oci8` is correctly listed there:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
oci8
```