# Docker nginx php-fpm 7.4 alpine with Oracle Instant Client in CentOS 7 - Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' & 'pdo_oci.so'

Tags: php, oracle, docker, centos, oracle-call-interface

I am new to setting up Oracle Database on a server, and I am setting up NGINX PHP-FPM 7.4 Alpine and Oracle Database using Docker on a CentOS7 server (centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64).

I have already successfully installed the Oracle Database in Docker, **so my next objective is to be able to connect to the Oracle Database using the function `oci_connect` in PHP**. This is where I am stuck. I have been [following this](https://github.com/lorisleiva/laravel-docker/issues/1#issuecomment-398667603) and downloading the required software such as the Oracle Instant Client. (I used the latest version as of this writing: instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru )

I got the following files for docker-compose:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/web
      - ./log:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: always
  phpfpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/web
```

**php-fpm/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/web

# custom.ini is basically my php.ini
ADD custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    libzip-dev \
    curl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    php7-openssl

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    curl \
    dom \
    gd \
    json \
    tokenizer \
    zip 


# Install Oracle Instantclient
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle \
    && cd /opt/oracle 


ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN rm -rf /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/*

RUN unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && ln -sf /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so.19.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -sf /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntshcore.so.19.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntshcore.so \
    && ln -sf /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libocci.so.19.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libocci.so \
    && rm -rf /opt/oracle/*.zip

# Install Oracle extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6,19.1 \
       && echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/' | pecl install oci8 \
       && docker-php-ext-install \
               pdo_oci \
       && docker-php-ext-enable \
               oci8

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

In addition, I have also added these Oracle related 'extension' into **custom.ini** (basically my php.ini) which is referred in php-fpm/Dockerfile above:

```
expose_php = Off
extension=oci8.so
extension=pdo_oci.so
```

---

**docker-compose up**

When I do docker-compose up, I see that the build process could be completed but I got into the following warnings in the build output:

```
...
...

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

...
...
```

This "Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' and 'pdo_oci.so'" occurs in the build roughly 20 times.

After the whole build process is completed, php-fpm runs but it also have similar warning messages above:

```
Successfully built c5fe0a0bc6ab
Successfully tagged nginx-php_phpfpm:latest
Starting nginx-php_web_1    ... done
Creating nginx-php_phpfpm_1 ... done
Attaching to nginx-php_web_1, nginx-php_phpfpm_1
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6//libclntsh.so.19.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so.19.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6//libclntsh.so.19.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so.19.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
phpfpm_1  | [20-Mar-2020 11:30:03] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

---

**PHP Test**

I also tested this with a .php file:

```
<?php

  $objConnect = oci_connect('SYSTEM', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'x.x.x.x');
    if($objConnect)
    {
        echo "Oracle Server Connected";
    }     
?>
```

Obviously, this yields on the browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /var/www/web/public/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/web/public/index.php on line 3
```

---

**Looking into the container**

I also tried look into the container itself with : `docker exec -it 623 sh` to check into the directory the app is referring to:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902 # ls -la
total 2588
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            39 Mar 20 11:29 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            39 Mar 19 22:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        122288 Mar 20 11:28 curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        249824 Mar 20 11:28 dom.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        433280 Mar 20 11:29 gd.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         54944 Mar 20 11:29 json.so
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        911808 Mar 20 11:29 oci8.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        579504 Mar 19 22:43 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         51368 Mar 20 11:29 pdo_oci.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        108128 Mar 19 22:43 sodium.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         35952 Mar 20 11:29 tokenizer.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         89600 Mar 20 11:29 zip.so
```

I see that all the files are there, so what's with the `Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so` then? How come it cannot find the library when it is there in the container?

---

**Other things I have tried:**

I have also tried looking around StackOverflow, and tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833414/144201) but still, adding `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902` into my Dockerfile does NOT solve the problem.

---

Am I missing something in this case? What must I do in order for it to be able to resolve for the libraries? Or are there some incompatibility issues in this case?

Comment: Alpine doesn't have the required glibc.  I really, really recommend against using Alpine with Oracle libraries.  Other people have hacked it, e.g. see https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/30#issuecomment-599093266

Comment: PS there are various ways to install Instant Client in Docker.  See https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile and https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

Answer (score -1):

Add to your Dockerfile:

```
# ORACLE EXTENSION
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install wget bsdtar libaio1 && \
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf- -C /usr/local && \
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf-  -C /usr/local && \
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffeinalab/php-fpm-oci8/master/oracle/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip | bsdtar -xvf- -C /usr/local && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/instantclient && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.* /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/lib* /usr/lib && \
    ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus

RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient/' | pecl install oci8 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable oci8 \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci
```

Comment: Never download Instant Client from non-Oracle sites.  You can wget from Oracle itself, without needing a login or clickthrough.  Links are on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html  There's no reason to use 12.2.0.1.  Use 19c instead (this is really the renamed 12.2.x version).  The 19c version will connect to the same database versions that 12.2 does.