# install and enable OCI8 extension for php:8.1-fpm in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, laravel-9, oci8

I'm trying to install and enable OCI8 in dockerfile for php:8.1-fpm
image to ..

This is a part of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle
# Install Oracle Instantclient
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/216000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip \
&& wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/216000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip \
&& wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/216000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip \
&& unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle \
&& unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle \
&& unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle \
&& rm -rf *.zip \
&& mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_6 /opt/oracle/instantclient

#add oracle instantclient path to environment
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient/
RUN ldconfig

# Install Oracle extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient,21.1 \
&& echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | pecl install oci8 \
&& docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_oci \
&& docker-php-ext-enable \
        oci8
```

**full dockerfile** is [here](https://pastebin.com/18pnC7J7)

`docker-compose build`: Successfully built with this warning:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library libaio.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/instantclient_21_6/libclntsh.so.21.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

when I checked for the exited extensions using `RUN php -m` just after the installation is done with warnings, I have found out that oci8 is not installed.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I thought it was a path issue, but the real error which was clear in part of the warning message:

`Error loading shared library libaio.so.1: No such file or directory`

also this command shows what is exactly the missing libraries for `oci8.so`:

```
RUN ldd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/oci8.so
```

output:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4017a000)
        libclntsh.so.21.1 => /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.21.1 (0x00007fd247169000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd246fa0000)
        libnnz21.so => /opt/oracle/instantclient/libnnz21.so (0x00007fd24692b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd246925000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd2467e1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd2467bf000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd2467b2000)
        libaio.so.1 => not found
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fd246798000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd24b57f000)
        libclntshcore.so.21.1 => /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntshcore.so.21.1 (0x00007fd2461e8000)
        libaio.so.1 => not found
```

as the output says: `libaio.so.1` is missing.

I solved it by Installing these packages:

```
RUN apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev
```

## **Edit:**

I tried to rebuild the same version of the Dockerfile lately and I got an error installing OCI8, specifically while executing this command:

```
echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | pecl install oci8
```

`ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | pecl install oci8" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

after a careful search in the output of the build for more info about the error I found the problem in this line:
`#error Use PHP OCI8 3.2 for your version of PHP`

I don't know why it was working before, I think this specific version requirement was added lately, So simply I changed the command to install that specific version of OCI8

```
echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | pecl install oci8-3.2.1
```

Comment: That library is also mentioned in the Instant Client documentation

Comment: You helped me a lot. I was able to add this to `phpexperts/dockerize`.

Answer (score 2):

Set the system library search path to contain the Instant Client libraries before installing the PHP extensions.  The best way is to use `ldconfig` as recommended in the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).  In your case it would be:

```
RUN echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_6/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oic.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

This would also mean you can remove LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the step `RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_21_6/ php`.  In fact, that whole line isn't useful.

You may find some of the Instant Client tips in [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) useful.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, actually the problem was solved by changing the place of `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient` to be before installing PHP extensions, but I did not pay attention that I had a different error which I solved by installing the missing packages then I edited and answered my question which obviously has a different problem than the original one. I will keep the edited version of the question because the original one has a similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833041/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-so-php-7-2)