# Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (PHP 7.3)

Tags: docker, oci8

I'm using Docker environment, when I upload Docker I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8'
> (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8
> (Error loading shared library
> /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8: No such
> file or directory),
> /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8.so (Error
> loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed
> by /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1))) in Unknown on
> line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8 (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/oci8.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1))) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so (Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1)), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_oci.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
> I don't understand why the script try to launch this file: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so.so

I don't understand why the script try to launch this file:

> /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so.so

I tried some solutions seen in other threads around here, still without success.
[tried solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833041/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-so-php-7-2)

My Dockerfile:

```
# Oracle
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle && cd /opt/oracle

ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /opt/oracle
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /opt/oracle

RUN  unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntshcore.so.11.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntshcore.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libocci.so.11.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libocci.so \
    && rm -rf /opt/oracle/*.zip

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
RUN docker-php-ext-install oci8
RUN docker-php-ext-enable oci8
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2,11.2
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a manual install of the libnsl package. E.g on Oracle Linux 8 you would do something like:

```
RUN yum install -y libnsl
```

There were some changes to libnsl since the older Oracle client libraries were released.  I'm guessing you are using a 'newer' operating system version.

The requirement to manually add libnsl is noted on the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/au/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).

I would also suggest updating from Oracle 11.